# Getting Modifying State During View Update When Using Map in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var defaultRegion: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: 29.726819, longitude: -95.393692), latitudinalMeters: 100, longitudinalMeters: 100)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Map(coordinateRegion: $defaultRegion)
            .padding()
            
    }
}
```

Whenever I run this code I get the following warning:

```
[SwiftUI] Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't care about ever reading the region, I found that something like this suppressed the warnings. I leave it to the more knowledgeable to determine if it's the correct solution:

```
struct ContentView: View {

var defaultRegion: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: 29.726819, longitude: -95.393692), latitudinalMeters: 100, longitudinalMeters: 100)

var body: some View {
    
    Map(coordinateRegion: Binding.constant(defaultRegion))
        .padding()
        
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).